# Shortest Path between two points on a 'Tube Map' along with MySQL

Tags: c#, php, distance, graph-algorithm

Anyone knows what is a code for selecting a points on a Image and then saving it. I'm using a Dreamweaver CS5 for creating an Hotspots over an image of london underground [Tube Map]. But what is a way for selecting the two points.

As I'm working on a journey planner which is a clickable interface so I need to select any two points on a 'Tube Map' and then obtain a shortest path between any 2 selected points. Similar to the one like this http://www.mtr.com.hk/jplanner/flash_chi/index.php

I've the information for Tube Map and created all in MySQL or PhpMyAdmin, which I got it from Wikipedia http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/London_Underground_geographic_maps/SQL
Someone please assist me in where to start with it's confusing. I'm using Wampserver2

Comment: Have you ever heard of the [Traveling Salesman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) problem?

Comment: Yes, I found various algorithms for shortest paths, But I want to go step-by-step so after creating an Hotspots on an image, I want the spots to be selected. What is the sourcecode for it in HTML (ImageMap Technique) or Javascript.

Comment: Actually it's a Clickable Map Journey Planner for london 'Tube Map' as it's a complex network so any solutions in PHP, or .NET with C# is appriciated.

Comment: My point was, it's not trivial. Depends on how "accurate" you want to be with your suggestion.

Comment: Similar to the one exactly like this application, http://www.mtr.com.hk/jplanner/flash_chi/index.php

Comment: I'm getting lost :)  Are you going to implement it, or are you looking for a web which has it already done?

Answer (score 3):

I've implemented this in SQL as a part of my thesis.
See here: http://ondra.zizka.cz/projekty/diplomka/DiplomovaPrace-OndrejZizka.pdf

It's in Czech but algorithms are SQL.

However my algorithm computes shortest connection at the current moment based on timetable schedules. I don't see timetable data in your data, so it should be easier - see Dijkstra's algorithm or A* or such.

Based on your comment at the other answer - I'm adding a link for you:

- **Dijkstra's** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm
- [**A* algorithm**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm)

Comment: These are the structures which are in my MySQL and PhpMyAdmin Database already created and where can I link this with an Image in Front-End i.e. a 'Tube Map'
-- Table structure for table links
--
CREATE TABLE links (
  station1 smallint NOT NULL default '0',
  station2 smallint NOT NULL default '0',
  line smallint NOT NULL default '0',
  UNIQUE (line,station1,station2) 
) ;

Comment: Hm, okay. 1) PhpMyAdmin is a frontend, it's irrelevant. 2) Linking an image in frontend with the structure in DB is task for PHP, in your case. I suggest you to overlay the image with a SVG graphics, or create a transparent image in PHP where you would draw the graphics, and overlay the map with it.

Comment: @Ondra: I wonder how you can solve a connection over many trains, i.e. if you need to change a train. Is this information somehow relevant for the graph? How did you use the momentan timetable? Do you use a bin-packing algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

You want to build a distance or time-consumption table of every possible connection then you can compute a shortest path with dijkstra. This isn't a travel-salesman-problem but it's related to graph algorithm in cs. Here is my solution for a tsp-solver and a deliver service and price table sorting: bit.ly/rdZxRo. It's all with php, mysql, ajax, typo3.

Comment: Ya, I saw several on A* and Dijkstra Algorithm in codeproject http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TubePlanner.aspx,
But its a windows apps I'm looking for Web Application with client server scenario.

Comment: Doesn't matter - the algorithm is abstract.

Comment: @Yes: Here is my solution for tsp and deliver service: http://bit.ly/rdZxRo. It's all with php, mysql, ajax, typo3.